# What early sources other than the books of Maccabees and Josephus are there for Judean rebellions under Antiochus IV?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome

Other than the books of Maccabees and Antiquities of the Jews (book XII) by Josephus, can anyone help me by pointing me to other early (3rd century or earlier) sources for the Judean rebellions under Antiochus IV?

I didn't notice any mention of them under Cassius Dio, or Livy (I may have missed them).

Any help appreciated. ,

Comment: The way this question is phrased implies that more should be expected. Two complete and independent sources is a pretty good amount for an ancient event.

Comment: I was just wondering if there were more. I assume from your answer that you aren't aware of any, and that those two are all there is.  Thank you for the reply.

Comment: @Glenn I do not see any answer around here, just a comment, and comments in their original function are meant to guide posters to improve their questions. Here: it may be read as to lower your expectations ("there must be…"), but also as "please indicate _why_ that may not suffice, for you, " as the default position of "alas, that's it". Hint: this was IMO a pretty _big_ event (bring a short description of it/link; some readers are unfamiliar with the terse info above;), and Josephus _may not_ be so independent from Maccabees as "two independent srcs" suggests?

Comment: @LangLangC : Thank you for the correction. I shouldn't have assumed that T.E.D. was familiar with the topic. And I can see that my question can be thought to assume there were other sources. I didn't mean it to I was just wondering whether there were other early sources.  In case Maccabees and Josephus were constructions under Constantine for example.

Comment: @Glenn That way lies madness. *Any* ancient source can be impugned because so little survives from those times. All we can do is cross-check documents against each other and with what archeological evidence exists and apply good sense to work things out as best we can.  Declaring awkward-to-our-theories documents to be forgeries is tempting, but really is just the other side of the credulity coin.  (Had Constantinople fallen even just a century later, copies of many more ancient might have survived.)

Comment: @MarkOlson 1304 was still before the Black Death.

Comment: I have no relevant expertise but suspect the "Sources" section of [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Jewish%E2%80%93Roman_War) is exhaustive.